# Error : An exception (first chance) at 0x76f6f9d2 in Boost_Mutex.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-mutex

I write a program to test multithreading. In `main` function a `thread t` is created. In `function D`, which is in `thread t`, two threads `tt` and `ttt` will be created. The function `Process` runs in `thread ttt` . In `Process` a member function `doAnotherThing` of `class Dat` will be called. In `thread tt` a member function `doOneThing` will be called.

When I debug this program, an error occured: `An exception (first chance) at 0x76f6f9d2 in Boost_Mutex.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.`

Sometimes **this error** occured instead of the error above :

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'oDat' was corrupted.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this Problem and modify the codes?

These are my codes:

"Dat.h"

```
#pragma once 

#ifndef DAT_H
#define DAT_H

#include <boost\thread\thread.hpp>
using namespace std;

class Dat 
{

public:
    Dat();
    ~Dat();
    void doOneThing();
    void doAnotherThing ();
private:
    boost::mutex omutex;

    int x;
};
#endif // DAT_H
```

"Dat.cpp"

```
#include "Dat.h"

Dat::Dat()
{

}

Dat::~Dat()
{

}

void Dat::doOneThing()
{
    x = 1;  
}

void Dat::doAnotherThing()
{
    omutex.lock();
    x = 2;
    omutex.unlock();
}
```

"main.cpp"

```
#include "Dat.h"
#include <boost\function.hpp>

struct Parameter // the Parameters of function Process and D
{
 Dat* pDat;
};
void Process(void*pParam)
{
    // init the parameter 
    parameter* pUserParams = (parameter*)pParam;
    pUserParams->pDat->doAnotherThing();
}

void D(void* pParam)
{
    // init the parameter 
    parameter* pUserParams = (parameter*)pParam;
    boost::function<void()> f;
    boost::thread ttt(Process, (void*)&pParam);
    f = boost::bind(&Dat::doOneThing, pUserParams->pDat);   
    // the capture thread will be started
    boost::thread tt(f);

    ttt.join();
    tt.join();
}

void main()
{
    Dat oDat;
    parameter pPara ;
    pPara.pDat = &oDat;
    boost::thread t(D,(void*)&pPara);
    t.join();
}
```

If you have suggestions to this statement of my quesion, pleas tell me and i will modify it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is this line:

```
boost::thread ttt(Process, (void*)&pParam);
```

You take the address of `pParam` (which is already a pointer), yielding a `void**`, and then cast it back to a `void*`. The C++ threading interface is type-safe. The fact that you have to cast is a strong indicator that you're doing something wrong. (Also, your usage of `void*` all over the place. This is needed for C threading interfaces, but not for C++.)

Anyway, in `Process` you then take the parameter, which points to `pParam`, and pretend that it points to your `pPara` object. (Why is that prefixed `p` anyway? It's not a pointer!) Then you reach into it to the `pDat` pointer, which is of course nonsense, because there's no `Parameter` struct there in the first place. So the pointer you get isn't valid, and doesn't point to a valid `Dat` struct, which means that the `mutex` in there isn't valid either, which means its internal thread handle isn't valid, so you finally get the crash you need when you try to lock the mutex.

Here's how you fix your code: get rid of all void pointer and get rid of all casts. Also, which not strictly necessary, you should also get rid of the variable prefixes. A redundant naming convention is bad enough, but an incorrectly applied redundant naming convention is a disaster.

You have one more error: you don't protect **all** your accesses to `x` with the mutex, just one. This is useless. You've still got the race condition. You have to protect all accesses to a shared variable. Also, you should use a `lock_guard` RAII object instead of manually calling `lock` and `unlock`, so that you can never forget to unlock.

Comment: There is no `Parameter` struct where the `pParam` argument of `Process` points, because the argument really points to the `pParam` argument of `D`, which is a `void*`. Basically, you messed up your pointers, and papered over it with casts.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.